# Flutter Error - The argument type 'MaterialStateProperty<RoundedRectangleBorder>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'OutlinedBorder

Tags: flutter, error-handling, flutter-layout, syntax-error

want to customize the button's default border radius but having the following error:
"The argument type 'MaterialStateProperty' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'OutlinedBorder"

```
Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              child: ElevatedButton(
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                          RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0))),
                      elevation: 0,
                      primary: Colors.white,
                      minimumSize: const Size.fromHeight(50)),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/home');
                    // Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/home');
                  },
                  child: const Text(
                    "Start",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 18,
                        color: Color.fromRGBO(86, 96, 49, 1)),
                  )),
            ),
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove MaterialStateProperty.all( or replace your code with below.

```
 Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
  child: ElevatedButton(
      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
          shape:RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
          ),
          elevation: 0,
          primary: Colors.white,
          minimumSize: const Size.fromHeight(50)),
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/home');
        // Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/home');
      },
      child: const Text(
        "Start",
        style: TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            fontSize: 18,
            color: Color.fromRGBO(86, 96, 49, 1)),
      )),
)
```

Answer (score 2):

That's helpful for the types, if you want to use you only have to add the generic type. [Documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/buttons)

```
 ElevatedButton(
      style: ButtonStyle(
          backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.red),
          shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
            const RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8)),
            ),
          )),
      child: const Text('Text'),
      onPressed: () {},
    );
```

Comment: Why did you post two similar answers in quick succession?